# Do abilities stick around after a champion's death?

Tags: league-of-legends

So there are a couple different categories of abilities that I'm wondering about. They may all act the same, but I think I've noticed them behave differently in game.

DoT effects? I assume Teemo's poison will continue to tick even if Teemo dies.

Anivia's Wall? Does it last the entire duration regardless of Anivia being alive or not? Or does it disappear on death?

What about Demacian Standard cast right before death by J4? Does that continue to apply the team buff for the duration or is it gone when he dies?

Gragas' Barrels and Lux's Lucent Singularity? I've seen these disappear at death and hang around  after the caster's death. My theory is that they will stick around if they have stopped moving by the time the caster has died.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion on a better way to categorize champion abilities please edit the post or suggest it in the comments. I couldn't think of criteria that covered the various examples concisely.

Comment: This might be too broad, to be honest, as it seems to vary between champions and abilities.

Comment: This will definitely depend on the champion and on the ability. Some last, some don't. The full list of examples would be quite exhausting to compile!

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was some pattern to what stayed around and what didn't as far as the answer went. If that turns out not to be the case then I wouldn't expect a list of all the champions abilities or anything (that would be a nightmare to keep up to date anyway). That would be a shame though, I think this could be some interesting knowledge if there is a pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some testing to show how the mechanics of abilities that create areas work.
The video shows Gragas' barrel despawning if it is in motion when you die, but it stays around to do  damage if it has stopped at time of death.

I also showed Anivia's skills. Crystallize (W) stays around for the full duration as expected. Flash Frost(Q) triggers automatically instead of traveling the full duration. Frostbite (E) connects regardless if you are dead or alive.

I also tested Jarvin the Fourth's Demacian Standard (E). It also stays around after death.

Finally, I tested with Lux since her Lucent Singularity was in question. Lucent Singularity (E) did land if you died while it was traveling and exploded on impact. Lucent Singularity (E) also exploded whenever you died if it was already placed. Light Binding (Q) also connected and CC's whatever is hit if you die while it is in flight. Finally, Prismatic Barrier (W) returns to your corpse even if you die while it is in flight.

We can also safely say that any ability that toggles or applies to your champion dies with your champion. Abilities that apply to other champions such as Lulu's Wild Growth, Teemo's poison, Vlad's hemoplague, Ignite, and the burn damage from Brand's passive all stay around for their duration. It is also safe to say traps and the like stay for the full duration, I'd further suggest that any time duration spell that is independent of the champion stays around (See J4's E and Anivia's W).

Comment: I feel like these examples provide pretty good coverage of various ability types, but if there are any that you feel are lacking please post and I'll work on getting them included.

Comment: As someone who used to main with Lux, your findings for her are interesting. I've always considered Lucent Singularity's effects after Lux's death to be inconsistent. For me, sometimes it would burst immediately at death, sometimes it would actually last the full 5 seconds before popping. I never tried to test it rigorously though, so I'm likely biased (the "DAMMIT IT NEVER BURSTS WHEN I WANT IT TO" type of bias =P)

Comment: Yeah, they surprised me also I thought I'd seen the singularity hang around after death longer than I was able to reproduce. It might be worth re-investigating to see if there are certain cases where it will hang around to taunt you.

Comment: I'll add that Karthus' Lay waste, if casted before the end of his passive but would blow after, when absolutely dead, won't do damage.

Answer (score 0):

This question is difficult to answer definitivly as the condition of death effecting each champion's on-going abilities is handled by the game on a 'case by case' basis. Some effects persist after death, such as Jarvon IV's Cataclysm, others do not such as Fiddlesticks' Crowstorm, and even others change from time to time such as Heimerdingers H-28G Evolution Turrets. (Previously Heimer's turrets did not persist after death, now they do.)

It is entirely possible that the persistance of the effect of a spell is determined by the mechanics of it's existence. It would seem that spells that are in some way *actively tied* to their champions such as Fiddlesticks' Crowstorm, Anivia's Blizzard, and Galio's Idol of Durand, immediately end upon death of the Champion. However spells that are in some way *independant* of their parent champion such as Thresh's The Box, Vicktor's Chaos Storm, or Vladimir's Hemoplague, continue to have persisting effects.

Comment: It seems like in the examples listed, the abilities independent of the champions persist. Fiddle's crowstorm is on the champion while J4's Cataclysm is not attached to him. Heimer's turret persisting can be explained by the the ability they added to have offline turrets perhaps?

Comment: I see where your going with this but I am still unsure. Anivia's Blizzard ends when she dies, Rumble's Ult (name escapes me) persists after he dies, Gragas' Barrels persist after he dies, but as far as I can tell when they explode they do no damage...

Comment: @Ender [They still do damage when they explode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqlhidZtwTo&t=9m43s).

Comment: @Ender I've also seen them disappear (that goes back to my still moving theory). Anivia's blizzard is a toggle ability, so still connected to a champion, no?

Answer (score 0):

Skills that dies with champion.

- Autoattacks
- Instant skills
- Summoners that affects you (Ghost)

Skills that **stick around without caster**.

- There are cooldown skills like a Gragas Barrel, J4 Standard, Anivia
  Crystalize, Lulu ulti that will end in max time. **This is the most part of skills.**
- Traps (Caitlin, Teemo, Nidalie) will end in max time not with champion death.
- Summoners (Ignite, Exhaust...)

**Skills that ends with champion death** - this is the smaller part of family. This are skills with casting time. Most of them are ultimates and killing such champion or going out of range gives a element of counterplay for enemies. This is based on my LoL knowledge so it might lack of some skills.

- Anivia ultimate
- Annie ultimate
- Fiddlesticks ultimate
- Galio ultimate
- Heimerdinger turrets
- Janna ultimate
- Kartus ultimate
- Lucian ultimate
- Maokai ultimate
- Miss Fortune ultimate
- Mordekaiser ultimate - The owned ghost is visible for brief second and then dies when you are dead :(
- Morgana ultimate
- Nunu ultimate
- Rammus ultimate
- Skarner ultimate
- Syndra ultimate
- Talon ultimate
- Urgot ultimate
- Viktor ultimate - Will be working but it will be unable to move

Comment: Because of the new patch Heimerdingers turrets stay after death.(They just de-activate)

Comment: Oh, didn't play him only against :) thanks!

Comment: AA's actually are homing and when they have been sent, they hit.

Answer (score -3):

Put simply, the ability will stick around after death ONLY if it is an active ability. For example, if Ashe uses her Ultimate (Enchanted Crystal Arrow) then the Ultimate ability will still last even after the death of the champion, in this case, Ashe.

But note, abilities which are passive, ie Teemo's Move Quick's passive will be lost upon death of the champion Teemo. But the active on Teemo's Ultimate, his Noxious Trap will remain even after his death.

Even after you are dead, the Cool Down of all abilites will keep counting down untill the ability is ready to use again.

Comment: I think this is not complete. Some active abilities like Lulu's whimsy will stop when she dies.

Comment: I agree with @M'vy. Ahri's charm is lost immediately after death. Or if she dies before her charm hits, it only deals damage (and does not CC the target)

Comment: Additionally, I'd go as far as to say this answer is also wrong. As cited by the OP, Teemo's poison continues to tick even after he dies. However, that poison is a *passive*.

Comment: didn't know about ahri charm, but it's only consistent, given the way the ability is explained and probably implemented: "the target moves towards ahri" (who just died and thus is not a "valid" "move toward"-target anymore)